# Matching modifying characters after pattern

Tags: perl

I did this almost 20 years ago, so I've forgotten much about Perl and I'm not finding an answer from Google.

I have a file with many Times Ten DB `create hash index` statements of the form

```
create unique hash index on MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE (Col1, Col2)  pages=####;
create hash index on MYSCHEMA.ANOTHER_TABLE (Col1, Col2)  pages=####;
```

I have a hash keyed by table names holding the desired values for "pages=###".

I have properly read the line into a string variable, and I need to know how to get the table name following `index on MYSCHEMA.` into a variable.

Also, how do I replace the numbers in `pages=####`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use matching in a list context to extract the table name.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @lines = (
    "create unique hash index on MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE (Col1, Col2)  pages=####;\n",
    "create hash index on MYSCHEMA.ANOTHER_TABLE (Col1, Col2)  pages=####;\n"
);

my %pages = ( MYTABLE => 12,
              ANOTHER_TABLE => 42,
);

for my $line (@lines) {
    my ($table) = $line =~ /index on MYSCHEMA\.(\w+)/;
    $line =~ s/pages=####/pages=$pages{$table}/;
    print $line;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Extract the schema name

```
my ($schema_name) = $line =~ s/MYSCHEMA\.([A-Z_]+)/;
```

Replace the numbers following `pages=`

```
$line =~ s/(pages=)(#+)/$1$number_replacement/;
```

This works with a few assumptions about the structure of the line -- that schema name contains only caps or underscore, and that numbers follow `=` without spaces.

---

A better way, provided by [Borodin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/622310/borodin) in a comment

```
$line =~ s/pages=\K#+/$number_replacement/;
```

The `\K` is a particular form of the *positive lookbehind* `(?<=pattern)`, a *zero-width assertion* that the given pattern preceded the current match position.  This form also discards all previous matches, so the substitution above won't touch `pages=` part. Thus there is no need for any capturing groups. See lookaround assertions [in perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind) and `\K` [in perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns) (scroll down a bit).

Comment: or `s/pages=\K#+/$number_replacement/`

Comment: @Borodin  Oh, yes, wonderful :) A perfect use for `\K` -- also cleaning it all up!